# Cannot upload file with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to upload a pdf file, but it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: cannot focus element

Below is the code:

```
public class FileUploadPopUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G://ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://pdf2doc.com/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("pick-files")).sendKeys("F:\\Selenium Complete Notes.pdf"); 
    }

}
```

This is to automate the file upload action.I want to upload a pdf file. Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload file you have to use `input` element with file type, but your `pick-files` selector is a `div`, that's why you got an error. Use `input[type=file]` css selector:

```
public class FileUploadPopUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G://ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://pdf2doc.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]")).sendKeys("F:\\Selenium Complete Notes.pdf"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I have a doubt..In this case we have to select div which has  wrapper in id?

Comment: input[type=file]..can this be used even if the html tag doesn't contain type attribute?

Comment: To upload file using Selenium you have to use input with file type

Answer (score 0):

if file input is not editable - you can try to change `value` attribute with JS:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'F:\\Selenium Complete Notes.pdf');", element);
```